# How to prevent QTabWidget scroll buttons from gaining focus?

Tags: python, pyqt, focus, pyqt5, qtabwidget

In the following code the red background will jump back and forth with each tab-key press. Adding more tabs (around eight for me) causes the tab-bar scroll buttons to appear, and causes a situation where a double tab-key press will be required.

Is there any way to prevent the scroll buttons from getting the keyboard focus?

```
# Testing with python 3.6.3 pip installed pyqt5 5.9.2 in virtualenv on Ubuntu
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.tabs_left = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs_left.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self._add_tab(self.tabs_left)
        self.tabs_right = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs_right.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self._add_tab(self.tabs_right)

        layout.addWidget(self.tabs_left)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabs_right)

        self.add_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add Tab')
        self.add_button.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        layout.addWidget(self.add_button)

        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self._add_tab_left)

    def _add_tab(self, tabs):
        edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        edit.setReadOnly(True)
        edit.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit:focus { background-color: red;}")
        tabs.addTab(edit, '{}'.format(tabs.count()))

    def _add_tab_left(self):
        self._add_tab(self.tabs_left)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by setting the focus-policy on the tab tool-buttons:

```
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    ...
    def _add_tab(self, tabs):
        ...
        for child in tabs.findChildren(QtWidgets.QToolButton):
            child.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```